# Passing values from one servlet to another

Tags: jsp, servlets, getparameter

I have a jsp with value String filesrno = "testvalue". Also I have a form I am submitting on this jsp.

```
<form action="Sortable"id="myform" method="post">
<input type="hidden" id="no1" name="filesrno">
<input type="hidden" id="no2" name="totalcount"> 
</form>
```

where Sortable is another Servlet and values are passed to this servlet 2.
I have the same value in Sortable Servlet too accessed using getParameter. I want to get this value in Servlet 3 named as TempServlet. Please help me get the value in the tempServpet using Servlet or JSP

Comment: It's not clear, please add code what you are doing and failing/missing

Comment: Thanks @user7294900  I have many servlets I am working with. So wanted to access one servlet data to another without requestdispatcher as there is some processing I want to do.

Comment: I got it finally and I posted the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After few hours of effort, I got to the solution using session.

In servlet 1 I added -

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("FileSrno", outputString6);
```

I had few processing after this and at the end forwarded to some random servlet.
In the main servlet, I accessed it using

```
int FileSrno= (int) request.getSession().getAttribute("FileSrno");
```